# Update Column based on condition and create a new row in another table for every update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to a one time script to run against a SQL-Server database.

I want to set the value of a column (columnA) to a value based on a column in another table (columnB) that each of my items being updated has a foreign key for - I have done this fine. What I finally want to do is for every item that i successfully updated, I want to create a row in another Table (essentially an audit table) based on the values of the item updated.

So my update sql looks like this

```
UPDATE [mainTable]
SET [mainTable].[columnA]=[otherTable].[columnB]
FROM [mainTable] 
INNER JOIN [otherTable]
ON [mainTable].[foreignKey]=ad.[primaryKey]
Where [mainTable].[columnA]<>[otherTable].[columnB]
```

That works great.

I also have a separate INSERT into statement that looks like this

```
INSERT INTO [auditTable] (
{various columnnames])
SELECT (
{some similar column names and also some different ones})
FROM [mainTable]
WHERE [mainTable].[columnA]=1
```

Now if I ran this just after the first insert statement it would create a row in the audit table for every row in the main table that have a columnA value of 1. That is not what I want.

I only want to Insert a new row into the auditTable if it was updated in the update command that ran. Is there way to do both the UPDATE and the INSERT INTO in one command based off the INNER JOIN?

Thanks

PS. As you might be able to tell, I am not hugely familar with SQL, I have spent a good hour searching google for info on this and haven't been able to find anything

Comment: Hint:  Look into `MERGE`.

Comment: If it is a one time script, you could use a cursor

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'll take a look thanks

Comment: @KristjanKica No idea what that is, but I shall google

Comment: @KristjanKica I looked into cursors and they worked great, I'm now torn between those and MarkD's answer about just updating the audit table first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would populate my audit table before the update, so that I can use the same conditions for populating the audit as I would for updating, You could wrap the two operations in a transaction to ensure they occur at the same time. e.g

```
BEGIN TRAN UpdateAndRecord

INSERT INTO AuditTable
column1
,column2
)
(Select Column1
,Column2
FROM [mainTable] 
INNER JOIN [otherTable]
ON [mainTable].[foreignKey]=ad.[primaryKey]
Where [mainTable].[columnA]<>[otherTable].[columnB]
)

UPDATE [mainTable]
SET [mainTable].[columnA]=[otherTable].[columnB]
FROM [mainTable] 
INNER JOIN [otherTable]
ON [mainTable].[foreignKey]=ad.[primaryKey]
Where [mainTable].[columnA]<>[otherTable].[columnB]

COMMIT TRAN UpdateAndRecord
```

Comment: Definately getting an upvote for something simple and nice. I'll give it a try and see if works

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `OUTPUT` clause here

```
 UPDATE [mainTable]
 SET [mainTable].[columnA]=[otherTable].[columnB]
 OUTPUT inserted.columnA, deleted.columnA
  INTO AuditTable(InsertedId,DeletedId)
 FROM [mainTable] 
 INNER JOIN [otherTable]
 ON [mainTable].[foreignKey]=ad.[primaryKey]
 WHERE [mainTable].[columnA]<>[otherTable].[columnB]
```

For Further [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

If you want get insert some other data like [otherTable].[somevalue] you can use `MERGE` with `OUTPUT` clause

```
 MERGE INTO Target AS T 
 USING Source s ON t.Id=s.Id 
 WHEN MATCHED THEN 
 UPDATE 
   SET t.co1=s.col1
 OUTPUT s.Id,DELETED.Id,INSERTED.ID INTO AuditTable(EntityId,OldId,NewId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you should use TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE, you can check how it is working there:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Basically you have to create a trigger on table where are you inserting, that trigger will execute after each insert.

Hope it will lead you on your way :)

Comment: " A trigger is a special type of stored procedure A trigger is a special type of stored procedure" - I dont wnat to create a stored procedure on the DB - this needs to run once and essentially leave nothing behind

Comment: Oh, I did not know that.